# How get Y for X d3-shape

Tags: javascript, react-native, d3.js

I need to get `Y` for `X` using `d3` in React Native.
I'm trying to get the value but all the solutions I tried didn't work

```html
const data: [number, number, number][] = chartData.map((p: any) => [
        p.x,
        p.y,
        p.dollar,
    ])

    const domain = {
        x: [Math.min(...data.map(([x]) => x)), Math.max(...data.map(([x]) => x))],
        y: [
            Math.min(...data.map(([, y]) => y)),
            Math.max(...data.map(([, y]) => y)),
        ],
        dollar: [
            Math.min(...data.map(([, , dollar]) => dollar)),
            Math.max(...data.map(([, , dollar]) => dollar)),
        ],
    }

    const range = {
        x: [0, width],
        y: [height, 0],
        dollar: [height, 0],
    }

    const scale = (v: number, d: number[], r: number[]) => {
        'worklet'
        return interpolate(v, d, r, Extrapolate.CLAMP)
    }

    const scaleInvert = (y: number, d: number[], r: number[]) => {
        'worklet'
        return interpolate(y, r, d, Extrapolate.CLAMP)
    }

    const d = shape
        .line()
        .x(([x], i) => scale(x, domain.x, range.x))
        .y(([, y]) => scale(y, domain.y, range.y))
        // @ts-ignore
        .curve(shape.curveBasis)(data) as string

    const path = parsePath(d)
```

I tried to use some libs like `import { getYForX } from 'react-native-redash'` but it not worked.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution? Struggling with the same problem